# Robot head, polo, transcendence and a helpful alien guide

Tags: story-identification, novel, soft-sci-fi

I read this paperback novel in the mid to late 1980's, it was second-hand at this point and might have been 10 or 15 years old - so perhaps from the late 1960s or some time in the '70s.

There was an interstellar setting, loosely allied worlds, perhaps some dangerous planets, a variety of nondescript aliens - the focus was not on the alienness but on the personal journey of the MC.

Guided by an alien companion with mild telepathic powers, the MC is lead on a journey to seek some greater truth, meaning. The journey might be the MC's or he's there to help the alien, I forget.

There was a key place the MC needed to find, perhaps part of a lost or hidden civilisation, perhaps left by the gods or superior beings. Seeking this place was where the adventure part occurs.

An ancient robot is said to possess the secret-location in it's memory, they seek and find the robot, but unfortunately its head is missing - and with it the key to the location of their goal.

Their journey takes them to a desert-land, inhabited by a primitive centaur-like race who are said to have stolen the robot's head some time before. Finding the centaur-peoples, these creatures completely ignorant of what they possess or it's implications for the wider galaxy or the personal journey of the MC, they are playing a polo-like game using the head as a puck.

After centuries and pretty beaten-up now the head and body of the robot are reunited, and the MC and companion get directions to their goal. They travel to some kind of walled-city where by some process I don't remember, the alien companion transcends reality becoming something akin to a force-ghost - and that's all I remember.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this might be [Destiny Doll](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1801698.Destiny_Doll) by Clifford D. Simak. It's been decades since I read this and I confess I remember little of the story, but on skimming the book I have found the parts about the robot with the missing head and the centaurs playing polo with it.

It starts with the spaceship captain *Mike Ross* being approached by a couple of adventurers. The want to find a telepathic robot (somewhat prosaically called *Roscoe*) that was built by the legendary adventurer *Lawrence Arlen Knight*. They find Roscoe but his head is missing because it was sold to the centaurs - sold, not stolen.

The group find the centaurs, who are indeed playing a polo like game with the head, and Mike has to fight a centaur in single combat to get the head back.

At this point I'm afraid my memory is letting me down and a skim of the book hasn't made the plot clear. However there are enough similarities to your description to make it a worthy suggestion.

Comment: Likely the one. I'll admit your skim reading proves more accurate than my fading memory. I'll wait the customary 24/48.